# ADSTS70000121: The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, outlook-restapi

I am trying to retrieve access token to call graph API however i keep getting

```
ADSTS70000121: The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint
```

I am sure that I have followed instruction given in official document [get access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

Here in the API end point URI: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**Postman setup**:
[image]
[image]

Comment: using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`, here the `xxx` is the value of your tenant name. For example, you may have an account which looks like `admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user):

The `{tenant}` value in the path of the request can be used to control who can sign into the application. The allowed values are `common` for both Microsoft accounts and work or school accounts, `organizations` for work or school accounts only, `consumers` for Microsoft accounts only, and tenant identifiers such as the tenant ID or domain name. For more detail, see [protocol basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).

---

First, you wrote `{tensnt}`, not `{tenant}`. Second, the curly brackets are showing that `{tenant}` is a variable. If you want to use a variable in postman, you need to initialize a variable with name and value and than you can write `{{VARIABLE_NAME}}` (double curly brackets!).

---

For the variable/placeholder, you can use `common`, `organizations`, `consumers` or a tenant identifier. Because you are using a personal Microsoft account, you have to choose the `/consumers` or `/common` endpoint. This will result in:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**OR**

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token`